# Java android Use filter: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.List.iterator()

Tags: java, android

In Adapter I have a filter and when I try find a something what I don't have on my List I see this:

```
07-31 16:17:07.025: E/AndroidRuntime(4634): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.List.iterator()' on a null object reference
07-31 16:17:07.025: E/AndroidRuntime(4634):     at pl.eltegps.inwentaryzja.offline.Adapter.getView(Adapter.java:105)
07-31 16:17:07.025: E/AndroidRuntime(4634):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2467)
07-31 16:17:07.025: E/AndroidRuntime(4634):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1894)
07-31 16:17:07.025: E/AndroidRuntime(4634):     at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1360)
07-31 16:17:07.025: E/AndroidRuntime(4634):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1673)
07-31 16:17:07.025: E/AndroidRuntime(4634):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2230)
07-31 16:17:07.025: E/AndroidRuntime(4634):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16001)
```

And this is my adapter:

```
public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    public Context context;
    public static ArrayList<AdapterRooteEntity> data;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    public static ArrayList<AdapterRooteEntity> mStringFilterList;
    private ValueFilter valueFilter;
    GPSTracker2 gps;
    int inx;

    public Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<AdapterRooteEntity> data) {
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mStringFilterList = data;
        getFilter();
        this.gps = new GPSTracker2(context);
        inx = 1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return data.indexOf(data.get(position)) + 1;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        AdapterRooteEntity row = data.get(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.all_object_holder, null);
        }

        DecimalFormat form = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

        RowBeanHolder holder = new RowBeanHolder();
        holder.tvAddress = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_address);
        holder.tvOwner = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_owner);
        holder.tvId = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_id);
        holder.tvDistance = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_distance);
        holder.tvId.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

        if (row != null) {
            holder.tvAddress.setText(row.getAddress());
            holder.tvOwner.setText(row.getOwner());
            holder.tvId.setText(getItemId(position) + "");
            inx++;
            if (row.getLat() > 0.0 && row.getLon() > 0.0) {
                if (gps.canGetLocation) {
                    double dis = Tools.distance(gps.getLatitude(), row.getLat(), gps.getLongitude(), gps.getLongitude());
                    data.get(position).setDistance(dis);
                    holder.tvDistance.setText(form.format(dis) + " km");
                }
            } else {
                holder.tvDistance.setText("?.? km");
            }

            if (RootActivity.chooseRow != null) {
                if (RootActivity.chooseRow.getAddress().equals(row.getAddress()) && RootActivity.chooseRow.getId() == row.getId()) {
                    convertView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.listSelectedItem));
                    holder.tvAddress.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    holder.tvOwner.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    holder.tvId.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    holder.tvDistance.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                } else {
                    convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                    holder.tvAddress.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    holder.tvOwner.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    holder.tvId.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    holder.tvDistance.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                }
            }
//            for(BIN bin : row.getBins()){
            if(!row.getBins().isEmpty()){
                for(int a= 0 ; a < row.getBins().size(); a++){
                    BIN bin = row.getBins().get(a);
                    if(StringUtils.isEmpty(bin.getBarcode()) && StringUtils.isEmpty(bin.getRfid1()) ){
                        row.setDone(false);
                    }

                }
            }
            if(row.isDone()){
                holder.tvId.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
            }else{
                holder.tvId.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
            }
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    private class RowBeanHolder {
        TextView tvAddress;
        TextView tvOwner;
        TextView tvId;
        TextView tvDistance;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (valueFilter == null) {

            valueFilter = new ValueFilter();
        }

        return valueFilter;
    }

    class ValueFilter extends Filter {

        //Invoked in a worker thread to filter the data according to the constraint.
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
                ArrayList<AdapterRooteEntity> filterList = new ArrayList<AdapterRooteEntity>();
                int ii = 1;
                for (int i = 0; i < mStringFilterList.size(); i++) {
                    if ((mStringFilterList.get(i).getAddress().toUpperCase()).contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {
                        AdapterRooteEntity row = new AdapterRooteEntity();
                        row.setAddress(mStringFilterList.get(i).getAddress());
                        row.setOwner(mStringFilterList.get(i).getOwner());
                        row.setId(ii);
                        filterList.add(row);
                        i++;
                    }
                }
                results.count = filterList.size();
                results.values = filterList;
            } else {
                results.count = mStringFilterList.size();
                results.values = mStringFilterList;
            }
            return results;
        }


        //Invoked in the UI thread to publish the filtering results in the user interface.
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            data = (ArrayList<AdapterRooteEntity>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

and here my app is crash . It happend when I write a char which I don't have on my List, when I comment this line it works corretly when I use a filter and try find what I don't have on my List I see empty List and my apk is not rashing

```
 if(!row.getBins().isEmpty()){
                for(int a= 0 ; a < row.getBins().size(); a++){
                    BIN bin = row.getBins().get(a);
                    if(StringUtils.isEmpty(bin.getBarcode()) && StringUtils.isEmpty(bin.getRfid1()) ){
                        row.setDone(false);
                    }

                }
            }
```

Comment: you need some custom adapter like: `class Adapter extends` [MatchableArrayAdapter](https://gist.github.com/pskink/2dd4d17a93caf02ff696533e82f952b0)`<AdapterRooteEntity> { ...` and override its `onBind()` and `matches()` methods

Comment: and of course you would need to override some public constructors (you can just override only one you use)